# Usage of automatic change tracking using EF Core from View in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have been reading about change tracking functionality of EF Core but I am unable to implement it in a way that it can catch all the changes done automatically from the view of ASP.NET Core MVC.

Here is the scenario: I have a list of records/entities in a view called `EmployeesList.cshtml` that looks like this:

```
@model List<Employees>

<form asp-action="UpdateEmployees">
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>
    <table class="table table-active">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label asp-for="@Model[0].Name" class="control-label"></label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label asp-for="@Model[0].Email" class="control-label"></label>
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr data-id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-id="@Model[i].Id" type="button" class="btn btn-danger employeeRemoval" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletePopup">X</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input name="command" type='submit' value='Save' class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="command" type='submit' value='Clear' class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

I want to apply CRUD on them (Save Update, add new and delete) and so far I was about to handle update and delete this way:

```
public IActionResult UpdateEmployees(List<Employees> employees, string command)
{
    if (command == "Save")
    {
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            _context.Employees.Update(employee);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();             
    }
    return RedirectToAction("EmployeesList");
}

// This Action is called via Ajax that passing the Id of the records.
public JsonResult RemoveEmployeeRecord(int id)
{
        var employee = new Employees(){ Id=id };
        _context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return new JsonResult(id);
}
```

And the current View rendered looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to handle adding a new row functionality so that user can click a "+" button at the bottom of the list to add more records. If users are simply adding records only without updating anything else then I think with some ajax I can make it happen.

However, I want to achieve adding record by simply updating the `DbContext` from the view (so the change tracking can handle it themselves, and I can just call save.changes), except I don't know how to approach this.

Can anyone help me to shed some light on whether this is plausible? or I will have to do it manually?

And if possible, can you please tell me whether my current implementation of update is bad? I feel like looping over every record and attach them to the context is bad when there are lots of records.

Comment: Manually. You need to do it manually to get it right.(From my expertise) -And, **yes, it is a bad implementation of Update if there are a lot of records. If there are only 2-4, it would be fine, otherwise, it just gets stuck.**

Comment: If you can update your question with the source code for the buttons, then I think I may be able to help more.

Comment: @Momoro Can you please give me some advice how to improve the implementation of Update? Also, I am not sure which buttons' codes you are mentioning but if you are talking about the button inside the <tr> then it is just opening up a boostrap modal, then pass the id to the RemoveEmployeeRecord Action via ajax (nothing special really).

Comment: My concern with the update is: Why have `if command=="save"`? If you don't have a `else if (command=="dont save")` then why have save at all? If the method is being called regularly, then remove `if (command=="save")"`, because there is no other command suggesting that it won't save, such as `command="dont save"`.

Comment: Also, what I mean by `button`, is I would like to see how you are calling the `Update` and `Remove` methods :)

Comment: @Momoro ah, You see, it is the asp-action="UpdateEmployees" at the top of the form. And about the command="save", i was just leaving it here for the time being (I may add logic to it later on)

Comment: Oh, Now I understand the `"save"` part :)